# xslt transform with xml that contains html - how to keep html formatting?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xsl-fo

Doing an xslt transform of **xml -> pdf**.  I have **one** input node that contains HTML (with tables, bolds, underlines, br's).

My xslt transform works perfectly other than the part for the HTML node.

Is there a way of preserving the formatting of the HTML content in that one node on the way through?

ie.

XSLT

```
<fo:block>
    <xsl:value-of select="Report/report/body"/>    <--preserve html formatting in this
</fo:block>
```

XML DATA

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<Report>
    <somenode>somenode_child_data</somenode>
    <someothernode>someothernode_child_data</someothernode>
    <report>
<!-- I WANT TO PRESERVE THE FORMATTING IN THE BODY NODE BELOW -->
        <body>REPORT <br/>
            <b>
                <u>Indication</u>
            </b>
            <br/>
            <table style="font-family:Lucida Sans Unicode; font-size:x-small; color:slategray;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <br/>Fetal wellbeing<br/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <b>
                <u>History</u>
            </b>
            <br/>
            <table style="font-family:Lucida Sans Unicode; font-size:x-small; color:slategray;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <br/>Rhesus:</td>
                    <td>\T\nbsp;\T\nbsp;\T\nbsp;\T\nbsp;Rh positive<br/>Other:</td>
                    <td>\T\nbsp;\T\nbsp;\T\nbsp;\T\nbsp;Pre-existing hypertension<br/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </body>
    </report>
</Report>
```

Comment: If the HTML is not XHTML (i.e. syntacticallly valid XML) you cannot process it with XSLT.  XSLT requires valid XML input, and regular HTML is not valid XML.

Comment: No, you’ll have to transform everything to its XSL-FO equivalent. So `table` becomes `fo:table`, `b` and `u` become `fo:inline`, etc.

Comment: is that this?.......`<xsl:template match="table">
 <fo:table space-before="0.5em" space-after="0.5em" table-layout="fixed">
  <fo:table-body>
   <xsl:apply-templates />
  </fo:table-body>
 </fo:table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tr">
 <fo:table-row>
  <xsl:apply-templates/> 
 </fo:table-row>
</xsl:template>`

Comment: You will also need to transform the text. `\T` and `\nbsp;` are just text to HTML, but I doubt that you want to see them in your formatted output.  Presumably, `\nbsp;` represents `&nbsp;` (`&#xA0;`), and maybe `\T` means a tab character.  Unless your tables all use the same formatting, you're going to have to parse or pattern-match the `style` attributes to work out what properties to set.